# To find the number of license plates consisting of six upper case alphabets where at least four of them is $A$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, combinations

To find the number of license plates consisting of six upper case alphabets where at least four of them is $A$.

So we break the case:

Exactly $4-A's$: Choose $4$ positions among $6$ in $\binom{6}{4}$ ways and the remaining we can choose in $25^2$ ways.

Exactly $5-A's$: Choose $5$ positions among $6$ in $\binom{6}{5}$ ways and the remaining we can choose in $25$ ways.

Finally, all of them are $A's$.

Hence total number of required ways $= \binom{6}{4}*25^2 + \binom{6}{5}*25 + 1.$

---

Is the argument correct?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing to answer...

Comment: Your answer is cool ! but if you want much powerful method that can help you for solving more complex questions , i am ready for answering , just ping me